# Can the title of the question not be a link when viewing a single question (and its answers)?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

The title pretty much says it. Question's title while viewing a single question and its answers currently is a link that leads to the same page and usually browsers make it really hard to select (and then copy) part of the link's text.

Sometimes questions have interesting things that I'd like to search more about them and are hard to "re-type" (different alphabet, includes characters I do not know how to reproduce on my keyboard).

What is the reason behind the title of the question being a link while viewing same question?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Chrome has this nice feature that you can select the link text by holding the ALT key.

Comment: if you're into userscipts you might try https://stackapps.com/questions/7403/more-share-links-markdown-html-bbcode it is not 100% what you're looking for but might be helpful to some extent.

Comment: This might also be done with a browser extension like [stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) and custom CSS applies to the questions that invokes, among other visuals, something like `pointer-events: none;`. You'd just have to make sure that question title links can be specifically selected as opposed to other links. (Although I'm not sure if disabling pointer events would let you select the text with your mouse . . .)

Comment: @rene Firefox also uses the Alt-drag technique to let you select text that's part of a link.

Comment: @rene Thank you for the shortcut, but sometimes I'm only able to use the trackpad with 1 hand. I was also wondering why is it a link at all.

Comment: The reason it is a link is because that is how things were done in 2008? Problem is if you remove the anchor you lose where you can always find the link to the question. That should be added back somewhere then. Maybe in the clutter that got recently added under the title. It probably breaks a few 1000 users muscle memory that now rely on the title being a link ....

Comment: Related: [Can't select text within the question title](/q/248065/289905).